# What is the difference between scalar types and aggregate types in C？

Tags: c, types, aggregate, scalar

I have read a book called "Pointers On C". In that book, there is a type called scalar types.

I know that arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types, but I want to know what is the  difference between scalar type and aggregate type and what occasion use them?

Answer (score 17):

#### C11-§6.2.5 Types (p21):

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called *scalar types*. Array and structure types are collectively called *aggregate types*.<sup>46)</sup>

Scalar data types can hold only single data item while aggregate types can hold more than one data items.

```
int a;             //Scalar Type
char c;            //Scalar Type
float *p;          //Scalar Type
char str[10];      //Aggregate Type
struct s{
    int a;
    float b[5];
} ss;              //Aggregate Type
```

---

<sub>46) Note that aggregate type does not include union type because an object with union type can only contain one member at a time.</sub>

Comment: Why it has two types, scalar and aggregate? And what is the different between them?

Comment: *Why it has two types*: Because C standard committee or may be language writer decided that.  *And what is the different between them?*: It is already mention in the answer. Let me explain it further.

Comment: Is a `union` a scalar type though?  Or is it a different beast from either scalars or aggregates?  It's neither an arithmetic type nor a pointer type, and a union can contain an aggregate.

Comment: @JoeZ In fact union doesn't fall under either scalar or aggregate type but it is in itself a new type! Though this is not mentioned in the standard anywhere explicitly, you can say that apart from scalar and aggregate there is a new type called `union`.

Answer (score 4):

As the word aggregation itself implies aggregation types are composed from other types.

In C aggregation types are array and structure types.

Take into account that an aggregation type can include another aggregation type.

Here is an example of aggregation types

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    struct TLine
    {
        struct TPoint
        {
            int x;
            int y;
        } first, second;
    } lines[10] = { [0] = { { 0, 0 }, { 10, 10 } } };

    printf( "lines[%d].first = { %d, %d }, lines[%d].second = { %d, %d }\n", 
            0, lines[0].first.x, lines[0].first.y, 
            0, lines[0].second.x, lines[0].second.y );
}
```

The program output is

```
lines[0].first = { 0, 0 }, lines[0].second = { 10, 10 }
```

The structure `TLine` is an aggregation type that contains another aggregation type definition `struct TPoint`. And `lines` is an object of one more aggrefation type - array of TLines.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [here](https://www.pgroup.com/products/freepgi/freepgi_ref/ch03.html):

**C Scalar**

> “C Scalar Data Types” lists C scalar data types, providing their size and format. The alignment of a scalar data type is equal to its size. “Scalar Alignment” shows scalar alignments that apply to individual scalars and to scalars that are elements of an array or members of a structure or union. Wide characters are supported (character constants prefixed with an L). The size of each wide character is 4 bytes.

**C Aggregate Data Types**

> An aggregate data type consists of one or more scalar data type. You can declare the following aggregate data types:
>
> - Array
> - Union
> - Struct

This was just a brief definition, but the link I've given has enormous content.

To make it more clear, here's a flowchart:

[image]

Here's an even more detailed flowchart:

[image]

Comment: The 2nd pic (Ada types) detracts from this otherwise fine C answer.  Suggest removing it.

Comment: The standard explicitly excludes union from the set of aggregate types.

Answer (score 0):

The internet can be your friend! But, a scalar type is a type for which there exists an arithmetic for its values (integers, floats, pointers), and a aggregate type is just a type for which values are tuples of values, i.e. an aggregation of values, a structure, and for which there is no *natural* arithmetic (ex.: a person described by its name and age, you can't add or multiply two persons...).