# OpenMP atomic on return values

Tags: c++, openmp

I have some trouble understanding the definition of scalar expression in OpenMP.

In particular, I thought that calling a function and using its return value in an atomic expression is not allowed.

Looking at [Compiler Explorer asm code](https://godbolt.org/z/j433nnPKW), it seems to me as it is atomic, though.

Maybe someone can clarify this.

```
#include <cmath>

int f() { return sin(2); }

int main()
{
   int i=5;
   #pragma omp atomic
   i += f();
   return i; 
}
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You don't need the header to use the pragmas, just the compiler flag

Comment: @Homer512: that's good to know.  I'd still like to be sure that OP has actually engaged OpenMP.  Perhaps we will be enlightened ...

Comment: see https://www.godbolt.org/z/j433nnPKW the asm output shows a call    _vcomp_atomic_add_i4

Comment: The function call isn't atomic, the `+=` is. As you can see in the [official examples](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf) (page 178), this is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: *Scalar expression* is not OpenMP specific but related to the core language. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722514/what-is-the-difference-between-scalar-types-and-aggregate-types-in-c) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ScalarType) you can read about which types are scalar. If your function returns a scalar type, then it is a valid scalar expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@paleonix comment is a good answer, so I'm expanding it a little here.

The important point is that the atomicity is an issue **only** for the read/modify/write operation expressed by the `+=` operator.

How you generate the value to be added is irrelevant, and what happens during generating that value is unaffected by the `atomic` pragma, so can still contain races (should you want them :-)).

Of course, this is unlike the use of a critical section, where the whole scope of the critical region is protected.